# How to create custom theme in websphere portal 8.5 (EAR in RAD)?

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Developing%20Themes%20for%20WebSphere%20Portal%208.5

I have this link to create custom theme in portal 8.5, but its from webdav but my requirement is bit different, Custom theme should be in RAD as a EAR, So that no need to connect webdav for the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try it on Portal 8.5, but this guide describes how you can package a theme in a ear file and install it using RAD

[Theme Ear file deployment step by step guide](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Deploying_and_developing_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_8_themes_A_step-by-step_guide)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the links below:

- [Developing IBM WebSphere Portal 8.5 EAR Themes: A Step-by-Step Guide](https://developer.ibm.com/digexp/blog/2015/05/26/developing-ibm-websphere-portal-8-5-ear-themes-a-step-by-step-guide/)
- [Developing Themes for WebSphere Portal 8.5](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Developing%20Themes%20for%20WebSphere%20Portal%208.5)
- [Custom Theme Creation WebSphere Portal 8.5 CF1](https://www.slideshare.net/michelebuccarello/custom-theme-creation-websphere-portal-85)
- [How do I create a copy of the WebSphere Portal V8.5 theme? 1/7 - Copy the static theme resources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMmeynv8ke0)